# The lowdown on paid SSL and dedicated IP?

Tags: windows-xp, ssl

I've been seeing conflicting answers with regards to using dedicated IP when using paid SSL. Some say you need a dedicated IP to cater website visitors with old systems (e.g., Windows XP) some say it doesn't matter.

Let's say your using a paid SSL like PositiveSSL, do you really need a dedicated IP so you can cater website visitors that uses Windows XP?

Answer (score 3):

The key here is [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). This is not supported on older browsers (and notoriously not on Windows XP (actually IE <7), but also older Android version for example). It doesn't have anything to do with the SSL certificate being free or not.

Check the compatibility sheet in the Wikipedia article mentioned. Determine if it's worth it for *you* to handle the overhead of dedicated IPs for the small and shrinking group of users that are still on these legacy systems.

Comment: Does this mean that if we use PositiveSSL with a dedicated IP then older browsers will have no issue with our websites?

Comment: Yes, PostiveSSL is supported on IE 6 (Windows XP). A full list of supported browsers is on https://www.positivessl.com/browser-compatibility.php

Comment: Came across this article: https://ventraip.com.au/faq/article/need-dedicated-ip-address-ssl-certificate/ it says "those older browsers that don’t support SNI actually don’t support any SSL (either on a shared or Dedicated IP address) given that the minimum requirement on modern servers now is TLS1.2". Does this mean that today, it really doesn't matter anymore if SSL has dedicated IP or not because the old practice of having a dedicated IP for SSL has security issues already?

Comment: Depends on how you configure your webserver. You can still configure your webserver to support SSL1.0, but most security experts would advise against it. It carries risks, but this goes way to far for comment discussion on SuperUser.